# How can I create a single CSS that works for Android & iOS browsers in terms of x2 retina dimensions

Tags: css, web, mobile-website

Mobile Safari multiplies all my CSS dimensions by two, so if I write a top bar with 44px height, it appears as I want on the iOS, but half the size on Android chrome.

How can I write a CSS that works for both browsers?

Comment: have you tried other units for the length declarations? e.g. cm, em, pt, %, ...

Comment: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/

Comment: Can you get a native looking iOS toolbar div with 88px height without using pixel units?

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling with Grunt, you can simply create two target CSS files,
android.css, iOS.css - and compile each with a parameters dictionary for example

{ factor: 1}, {factor:2},

and this way, 2 css files will be created with two different dimensions.